# What is the difference between VQFP, HVQFP, TQFP & PQFP?

Tags: pcb, integrated-circuit, packages, tqfp

VSC7145XRU-31/C  - this IC uses PQFP package

the replacement component for that TLK2201 uses HVQFP package

also TLK2541 uses TQFP

that's why i wanted to know whats the clear difference between them

Answer (score 11):

- **VQFP** - Very Thin Quad Flat Pack. Around 0.8 mm thick.
- **HVQFP** - Heatsink Very thin Quad Flat Pack. Also around 0.8 mm.
- **TQFP** - Thin Quad Flat Pack. Typically 1mm thick.
- **LQFP** - Low-profile Quad Flat Pack. Typically 1.4 mm thick.
- **PQFP** - Plastic Quad Flat Pack. Thickness from 2 mm up-to 3.8 mm.

Since you were interested in HVQFP, here's an image from Digikey. This one allows you to mount a heatsink at the top for better dissipation.
[image]